# Which file formats can be previewed on CKAN Data Preview tool?

Tags: preview, file-format, ckan

I am working on CKAN and will like to know the appropriate file formats that can be previewed on CKAN. I could not find any information on this topic online, so I decided to start this topic and hope to garner more responses on this which will be useful to CKAN developers in future. Here's a list of file formats that I have gathered after experimenting with my own CKAN and looking through other CKAN instances such as those from UK and Australia.

**Can** be previewed:

- CSV (Comma separated values)
- XLS (Microsoft Excel Binary File Format)
- HTML (HyperText Markup Language)
- JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
- PDF (Portable Document Format)
- RSS (Really Simple Syndication)
- TXT (Plain Text)
- WMS (Web Map Service)
- XML (eXtensible Markup Language)

**Cannot** be previewed:

- DOC (Microsoft Word)
- RDF (Resource Description Framework)
- HTML (HyperText Markup Language)
- KML (Keyhole Markup Language)
- SHP (Shapefile)
- WFS (Web Feature Service)
- XLSX (Microsoft Excel Open XML Document)
- ZIP (archive)

Help add on to my list and correct me if any of the above is wrong, then I will update the list above. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

For each ckan release, the data viewer's functionality may differ.

Refer to the DataViewer section in the documents of the CKAN version that you are using.

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

With some simple tweaks to the config file XLSX files can be previewed, as can Tab separated text files (tsv format/extension).

Edit the config.ini file to include

```
ckan.datapusher.formats = csv xls xlsx tsv application/csv application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

HTML and RDF are also previwable:
refer CKAN documentation http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html?highlight=preview#ckan-preview-loadable